# How can I stop LaTeX from compiling a part of the document again?

Tags: compiling, random

I have a personal journal template that I use daily to make notes. It is based on the `researchjournal` template available on overleaf. Now, I added a command to include a random graphic (from a selection available in the folder) for each day using the following:

```
\usepackage{lcg}
\reinitrand[counter=sec,first=1,last=4]
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printrandom}{\two@digits{\thesec}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\printrandom}{\ifnum\value{sec}<10 0\fi\arabic{sec}}
\newcommand{\picture}{\rand\includegraphics[width=2cm]{img/picture (\printrandom )}}
```

However, each time I compile for the new day, the pictures change for all the days. If I comment the '\picture' out, then predictably, the pictures disappear. Is there a way I can stop this from happening? i.e., Once a picture is chosen for a day, it should remain the same even when the document is recompiled.

Comment: use `seed=123` (any number bigger than 0) then you get a repeatable sequence